# Harbor installation via Bitnami helm chart expose via host machine ingress controller (not External Load Balancers) on single node microk8s cluster

Tags: bitnami, microk8s, ingress-controller, harbor

it is about to expose service via ingress rules and ingress controller , i do installation of harbor registry via helm chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/harbor and default service expose method is to bind service to external load balancer, since i have single ubuntu machine with microk8s i want to expose via host machine ingress controller, i do it but by overriding values.yaml files from helm, chart repo

```
global:  

storageClass: "ssd-hostpath"


externalURL: https://core.ip.nip.io

exposureType: ingress


# service:
#   type: LoadBalancer

ingress:
  core:
    #ingressClassName: "contour"
    hostname: core.ip.nip.io
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: contour
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging-cluster-issuer
      ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    tls: true  
    # secrets: 
    # - name: nip-io-lets-encr-stage-tls-cert
  notary:
    #ingressClassName: ""
    hostname: notary.ip .nip.io
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: contour
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging-cluster-issuer
      ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    tls: true  
    # secrets: 
    # - name: nip-io-lets-encr-stage-tls-cert
```

But in this case strangely pods are failing ang give  network error , just want to know if anyone could share sample installation of bitnami/harbor with exposing via ingress controller on same machine

Comment: What is the events you get from Kubernetes or what are the pod logs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I expose my Harbor using Traefik Ingress parameters from Bitnami Helm Chart `values.yaml` file. The Traefik ingress controller is exposed on node port 30080 and I enabled HTTP and HTTPS.

`values.yaml`

```yaml
externalURL: "http://core.harbor.domain:30080"
  expose:
    tls:
      enabled: true
      certSource: auto
    ingress:
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
        traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true" # Default conf
        ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0" # Default conf
```